# Querying and sorting embedded document in mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have three classes

```
class Post
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps
 belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => nil
 embeds_many :comments, :as => :commentable
 field :content, :type => String
end

class Commment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => nil
  embedded_in :commentable, :polymoriphic => true
end

class User
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  field :name, :type => String
end
```

Whenever the user creates a new comment, I want to compare the contents of it with the latest comment that the user has made. Here is my code that fetches the latest comment by the user:

```
comments_user=[]
Post.where("comments.user_id" => user.id).
     only(:comments).
     each {|p| comments_user += p.comments.where(:user_id => user.id).to_a}
latest_comment = comments_user.sort_by{|comment| comment[:updated_at]}.reverse.first
```

The above code gives me the result but the approach taken is not efficient as I have to traverse through all the posts that the user has commmented to find the latest comment. If any, can anyone provide me a more efficient solution to this problem?
Simply speaking, Isn't there any way I can get all the comments made by this user?

Answer (score 5):

This should fetch the latest user`s comment:

```
Post.where("comments.user_id" => user.id).order_by(:'comments.updated_at'.desc).limit(1).only(:comments).first
```

Comment: Actually, your code give me the latest post. I want the latest comment made by the user. This gives me the same result as yours: Post.where("comments.user_id" => user.id).order_by(:updated_at.desc).limit(1).only(:comments).first

Answer (score 3):

This is standard problem with embedding. It greatly improves some queries ("load post with all its comments"), but makes others non-efficient/impractical ("find latest comment of a user").

I see two options here:

- Keep embedding and duplicate data. That is, when user makes a comment, embed this comment to a post document and to the user document. This data duplication has its drawbacks, of course (what if you need to edit comments?);
- Stop embedding and start referencing. This means that comment is now a top level entity. You can't quickly load a post with comments, because there are no joins. But other queries are faster now, and there's no data duplication.

Comment: Ok...but right now I don't want to modify the model just to perform this query. Isn't there any workaround that gives me the result? Its fine if the result works for most of the cases..:)

Comment: yeah, it works but it is inefficient. It searches through all the posts that the user has commented. The solution is not scalable.If possible, I want something that is efficient and gives me the answer in most of the cases.

Comment: It's not possible to make efficient query with your current schema.